# Is it possible that $37 | 1+2^k$ for some $k$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

...I don't know how to show that or give a counterexample...does anyone know the answer? Thanks.

Comment: Can you compute the powers of $2$ modulo $37$?

Comment: Basically, there is such a $k$ if the order of $2$ modulo $37$ is even. The only possible odd orders for $2$ are $1,3,9$, so you need to check if $2^9-1$ is divisible by $37$. If it is, there is no $k$, if it not, there is such a $k$.

Comment: just for completion's sake $2^9 \equiv 31 \pmod{37}$

Comment: @Dando18 If $2^3\equiv 1\pmod {37}$  then $2^{9}\equiv 1\pmod{37}$, and same for $2^1$. You only need to check $2^9$.

Answer (score 2):

You looking for whether $2^k\equiv -1 \pmod{37}$.

Since $37$ is prime, we know that the multiplicative group modulo $37$ is cyclic of order $36$. $-1$ is the unique element of order $2$; and this is a power of $2$ if the order of $2$ is *even*.

The only possible *odd* orders are $1$, $3$, and $9$, so compute $2^1$, $2^3$ and $2^9$ modulo $37$ and see if any of them is $1$.

Comment: Alternatively, since $2$ is not a square modulo $37$, we have $2^{18}+1$ is divisible by $37$.

Comment: Curious about the downvote ... I could imagine someone downvoting for answering a PSQ (though I tried to make sure the OP would only be able to turn it into a hand-in-able solution if he understands what's going on), but there's no downvote or close vote on the _question_.

Comment: For any $k=18(2n-1);\;n>1$ we have $2^k+1\equiv 0 \pmod{37}$. I am not an expert but this happens

Answer (score 2):

Since $37$ is prime and $\gcd (37,2)=1$ we have,  modulo  $37,$ $$0\equiv 2^{36}-1\equiv (2^{18}-1)(2^{18}+1).$$  We have $$2^{18}+1\equiv (2^6)^3+1\equiv (2^6+1)\cdot ((2^6)^2-2^6+1).$$ We have $$(2^6)^2-2^6+1\equiv (2^6-1)^2+2^6\equiv 63^2+64\equiv (-11)^2+(-10)\equiv 121-10\equiv 37\cdot 3 \equiv 0.$$ Therefore $2^{18}+1\equiv 0 \pmod {37}.$

This method works because $37-1=36$ factors nicely. For the prime $179$ we have $0\equiv 2^{178}-1\equiv(2^{89}-1)(2^{89}+1) \pmod {179}$,  which will not give a quick easy A to whether $2^n+1\equiv 0\pmod {179}$ has a solution .

We can also use the above method to deduce that $2^{18}-1\equiv (2^6-1)((2^6)^2+2^6+1)\equiv (2^6-1)((2^6+1)^2-2^6)\not \equiv 0\pmod {37}$ and conclude from the first congruence above that $37$ must divide $2^{18}+1.$

Answer (score 1):

Since $2$ is not a square modulo $37$, you have that $2^{(37-1)/2}\equiv -1\pmod{37}$ so $2^{18}+1$ is divisible by $37$.

In general, if $p$ is a prime and $p\equiv 3,5\pmod{8}$ then $2^{(p-1)/2}+1$ is divisible by $p$.

If $p\equiv -1\pmod 8$ then $2$ is a square modulo $p$ and $-1$ is not a square modulo $8$, so there is no $k$ such that $p\mid 2^{k}+1$.

The case $p\equiv 1\pmod{8}$ varies for different $p$. For example, when $p=17$ you get $k=4$. But if $p=89$ then $2^{11}-1$ is divisible by $89$ and so no such $k$ exists.

Answer (score 0):

> One solution can be considered, as $k=18$.

If you don't know anything about number theory, you can check directly that:

$1+2^{18} = 262145 = 37 \times 7085$,

so $k=18$ is one solution.

Any solution must have the remaining $18$ module $37$; i.e.

$k_2=37+18=54$,

$k_3=2 \times 37+18=90$,

$k_4=3 \times 37+18=126$, etc.

---

If you want a more number theoretic solution; see here:

[How to prove 2 is a primitive root mod 37, without calculating all powers of 2 mod 37?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/960865/how-to-prove-2-is-a-primitive-root-mod-37-without-calculating-all-powers-of-2-m)